# Is a manifold $M$ which is a bundle over "perpendicular" submanifolds $A$ and $B$ always a Cartesian product?

Tags: manifolds, fiber-bundles

Suppose $M$ is manifold with submanifolds $A$ and $B$ whose intersection is a single point $x$. Suppose further that $M$ can be written as a fiber bundle over $A$ with $B$ being the fiber at $x$, and also that $M$ can be written as a fiber bundle over $B$ with $A$ being the fiber at x.

Does it follow that $M = A \times B$?

Comment: I haven't checked, but it sounds like the Klein bottle should be a counterexample

Answer (score 1):

The Klein bottle $K$ is a counterexample; since $K$ is a fiber bundle over $\mathbb{S}^1$ with fiber $\mathbb{S}^1$, but not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1\times\mathbb{S}^1$, it will suffice be able to find submanifolds $A$ and $B$ of $K$ each diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$ whose intersection is a single point. We can take $A$ and $B$ to be the centered horizontal and vertical lines going through the following representation of the Klein bottle:

[image]

Comment: Hi Zev, this is Injee. How are you?

Comment: Doing well; pretty busy at Chicago, though of course I procrastinate by coming here :) How are you?

Comment: This will not work. It's a bundle over the brown submanifold for sure. However, it is not a bundle over the green submanifold. Try to construct two non-brown fibers over the green submanifold - it cannot be done.

Comment: @James: My answer interpreted the phrase "can be written as" in the question as meaning "is diffeomorphic to". Since both $A$ and $B$ are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^1$, and $K$ is an $\mathbb{S}^1$-bundle over $\mathbb{S}^1$, we are free to interchange which "copy of $\mathbb{S}^1$ is $A$ and which is $B$.